# Creating/Pushing a tag for a private repository using gradle git plugin

Tags: github, gradle

I want to create a tag  and push it to my git repository(private).
Currently, my build.gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath "org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}     

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

and I have one task to clone repository :

```
task cloneTest <<{
def myRepo = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.clone(dir: 'C:\\Rep1', uri: 'https://bitbucket.org/..)

 }
```

Now, I want to add another task to create/Push a tag for a private GitHub repository and I have gone through this link http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/TagAddOp.html
But I am unable to use this in my gradle file. Currently I am writing like this

```
task createTag <<{
def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: 'C:\\Rep1')
grgit.tag.add(name: 'new-Tag', message: 'Some Message!')
}
```

This solution is given in http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/TagAddOp.html. But this says 'add cannot be reolved'. I don't know what is wrong. Is it with the grgit version I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked :

```
task createTag <<{                                                      
def grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(dir: 'dir_loc')        
grgit.tag.add(name: 'new-Tage', message: 'Some Message!')           
grgit.push(tags: true)                                              
}
```

I am able to see my tags in bitbucket

I am using classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.3.0' . It shows error on add and push keywords  but it runs successfully when I run the task on cli. So, this works completely fine